# How can I group by date time column for custom hour

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I group by date time column for custom hour, for example every 5 Hour or every 12 Hour or every 24 hour.

```
Select CreateOn, Count(*) From Table1
Group By ?????
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should select start date/time, '2011-01-01' in this example and then use [DATEDIFF() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) to get time difference in hours between start date and `CreateOn`. Then use `/` operator to get an integer interval number (5 hours in this example).

```
Select 
min(DATEADD(HOUR,DATEDIFF (HOUR,'2011-01-01',CreateOn )/5*5,'2011-01-01')) 
   as Start_time,
max(DATEADD(HOUR,(DATEDIFF (HOUR,'2011-01-01',CreateOn )/5+1)*5,'2011-01-01')) 
   as End_Time,
DATEDIFF (HOUR,'2011-01-01',CreateOn )/5 as Interval_Number, 
Count(*) as _Count
From Table1
Group By DATEDIFF (HOUR,'2011-01-01',CreateOn )/5
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you could try something like this:

```
SELECT CreateOn, Count(*) FROM Table1 GROUP BY (DATEPART(MINUTE, [Date]) % 12)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but this query make my all records into 12 group. I want to show statistic of register per custom step.

Comment: Im still not sure I fully understand what your asking but perhaps using the BETWEEN clause and not GROUP BY is what you need.  ie: SELECT CreateOn, Count(*) FROM Table1 WHERE DATEPART(HOUR,[DATE]) BETWEEN 1 AND 5